# How to draw a border line in the below edges of a semi circle using canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, paint, android-progressbar

Hi i have implemented a Semi circle and successfully draw a line in the border of a semi circle but i am not able to draw a line in the below edges. How to draw a line in the below edges. 
Please give me any suggestion.
Here my code is to draw a border:

```
 mRimWidth =40;
mContourSize = 1;
        InnerContour = new RectF(mCircleRectF.left + (mRimWidth / 2.0f)
                        + (mContourSize / 2.0f), mCircleRectF.top + (mRimWidth / 2.0f)
                        + (mContourSize / 2.0f), mCircleRectF.right
                        - (mRimWidth / 2.0f) - (mContourSize / 2.0f),
                        mCircleRectF.bottom - (mRimWidth / 2.0f)
                                - (mContourSize / 2.0f));

                OuterContour = new RectF(mCircleRectF.left - (mRimWidth / 2.0f)
                        - (mContourSize / 2.0f), mCircleRectF.top - (mRimWidth / 2.0f)
                        - (mContourSize / 2.0f), mCircleRectF.right
                        + (mRimWidth / 2.0f) + (mContourSize / 2.0f),
                        mCircleRectF.bottom + (mRimWidth / 2.0f)
                                + (mContourSize / 2.0f));

        canvas.drawArcOuterContour 160, 221, false, mPaint);
                canvas.drawArcInnerContour 160, 221, false, mPaint);
```

mpaint code is:

```
mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
        mPaint.setColor(mCircleProgressColor);
```

Now my image looking like below image:

[image]

But i want a image like below image:

[image]

Comment: I have not change your code. but I have own made a class

Comment: Oh is it looking like same..?

Comment: Can u share me the link

Comment: Yes. Have you inflate that custom view in your xml?

Comment: Yes Currently my view is inflated

Comment: Okay. Check my code http://hastebin.com/onagoqeduv.avrasm. For this view width and height must be the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101993/discussion-between-piku-and-piyush-gupta).

Comment: Piyush If u got solution please update it

Comment: Yes. Okay I will update you

Comment: Piku, did u solve the issue using the class which I have sent to you ?

Comment: Ya i modified it and now it is looking better

Comment: Piyush Can u come to chat